# JQuery hidden elements visible during page load

Tags: jquery

I'm working on [this interactive map](http://www.makejusticework.org.uk/community-sentences/interactive-map/) the problem I'm having is that the whole of the unit's content is visible during page load. Is there a technique I'm missing to hide this during load time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add following css:

```
.counties-container{
    display:none;
}

#st-c .counties-container{
    display:block;
}
```

Remove foloowing part from your map.js:

```
//this function hides each <div class="counties-container"> and is called onload and when the user selects a region

//ONLOAD - these several lines are used to help with graceful degradation (when the user doesn't have JavaScript enabled)
hideall(); //initiate the hideall function 
jQuery('#st-c').css("display","block");
```

This should solve the problem

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work - it just hid all of the text and menu content.

Comment: Made a minor correction. Just **dont remove** `hideAll()` function, keep it and it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Hiding your elements with jQuery require the DOM elements to be fully loaded, then your jQuery code will iterate and hide the targeted elements.

This will result in the problem you are talking about, so to avoid it, initialy set the `DISPLAY` property of your desired controls to `none;`, and then play with them as you want after the full load of your page is done.

If you are trying to hide it, then after it get loaded, show it up, consider utilizing the `load()` method if you are fetching your data from a service or a page inside your solution, or you can also utilize the `ready()` method of your DOM element.

References from jQuery Official documentation for both methods:

`Load` http://api.jquery.com/load/

`ready` http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Let me know if this helped you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could just add this attribute to each element you don't want to get displayed:

> style="display:none;"

If you just want that it isn't visible, but the place for it is already reserved
you could also use this:

> style="visibility:hidden;"

If it isn't possible to do this this way, you could try to add this somehow with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is add 'display:none' in your css, then .show() in your script.